# Gatsby - Updating context data on page load

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am using the Gatsby layout plugin, and want to update the state in the context provider with the page that is currently displayed. I can get it to update on a button click, as shown in this code:

```
import ContextConsumer from "../components/Context.js"

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      page: "portfolio"
    }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ContextConsumer>
          {({ data, set }) => (   
            <button onClick={() => set({curPage:this.state.page})}>Click</button>
          )}
        </ContextConsumer>
        <h1>This is the portfolio page</h1>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

However, I want the context to be updated on page load. I have tried using an immediately invoked arrow function, but this causes an error, "Maximum update depth exceeded".

Update 10.2: This is still confusing me. I can update and read context successfully from a button click, but still can't get it to work on page load, or from a lifecycle method. If you look at this sandbox, you will see what i mean: [codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-frog-ocnzl](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-frog-ocnzl). Clicking to the about page works fine; if you then click on "changer", it updates and successfully reads the new state from the context. However, if you click to the portfolio page, where i try to update on first render, it throws a bunch of errors. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: What is the result you're trying to achieve? Reading [the plugin's docs](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout), it doesn't seem like you should need to set context on component mount.

Comment: I am trying to trigger an animation each time the page reloads. This needs to be at the layout level (above the pages) so that it doesn’t rerender half way through.

Comment: Did you try to use `componentDidMount`? You can use [lifecycle methods](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) just like you would in any React app

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone else struggling with this I have found one solution, which is to wrap your component in a higher order component and pass in the context data as props. Here is an example:

```
//This is the original component
class Portfolio extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    this.props.set({ curPage: "portfolio" })  
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <h1>This is the {this.props.data.curPage} page</h1>
    );
  }
}

//...and this is the component that wraps it to pass in context data as a prop.
const PortfolioWrap = () => (
  <ContextConsumer>
    {({ data, set }) => (
      <Portfolio data={data} set={set}/>
    )}
  </ContextConsumer>
)
```